# Chrome This localhost page can’t be found

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, frontend

Hi guys i am trying to do reset password route with JWT included in the url
React Router DOM Route

```
                <Route
                path={'activate/:activateToken'}
                element={
                <p>Test</p>
                }
                />
```

**Expected Behavior**

To be able too access this url too

```
http://localhost:5173/activate/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Ijg5NDA5MTFjZjFAZmlyZWJveG1haWwubG9sIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg1MjY1NTUwLCJleHAiOjE2ODUzNTE5NTB9.wPnwsSo0Ksz6NYUt5XbpnI485v7FQST1yAZcLmCHJFQ
```

**Current Behavior**

```
Chrome Error message
chrome 
This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:5173/activate/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Ijg5NDA5MTFjZjFAZmlyZWJveG1haWwubG9sIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg1MjY1NTUwLCJleHAiOjE2ODUzNTE5NTB9.wPnwsSo0Ksz6NYUt5XbpnI485v7FQST1yAZcLmCHJFQ
HTTP ERROR 404
```

**What I tried**

I tried using shorter JWT token in the url and i was able to access this page !
IDK why is that is that because JWT have some special chars !

Comment: Can you confirm the the local server is running because this could easily be that the port isn't available and your browser cannot reach it.

Comment: Do you typically run your React app locally on port 5173? Typically it'll run on port 3000 (*or 3001*) by default. Check that you are (a) running the local dev server and (b) that you are referencing the correct PORT value.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the JWT token contains dots and slashes which can cause problems. You should look in to URL encoding in the server side and decoding the same on the frontend with something like useParams hook.